# How to use react-markdown library with helix (Clojurescript)?

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, react-markdown

My Goal is to render markdown files on my cljs webpage.

What I'm using:

- org.clojure/clojurescript 1.11.60
- lilactown/helix 0.1.6
- nodejs 18.9.1 and yarn 1.22.19

What I've tried:

```clj
;; blog.cljs
(ns mypage.blog
  (:require [helix.core :refer [defnc $]]
            [helix.hooks :as hooks]
            [helix.dom :as d]
            ["react-markdown" :as ReactMarkdown]))

(defnc blog []
  (d/div {:class "blog-section"}
    (ReactMarkdown {:source "# Header\nSome text..."})))

;; other ideas that also don't work:
;; ($ ReactMarkdown {:source "# Header\nSome text..."})
;; ($ ReactMarkdown "#Header\nsome text...")
;; (ReactMarkdown "# Header\nSome text...")
```

```clj
;; app.cljs
(ns mypage.app
  (:require [helix.core :refer [defnc $]]
            [helix.hooks :as hooks]
            [helix.dom :as d]
            ["react-dom" :as rdom]
            [mypage.blog :refer [blog]]))

(defnc app []
  (d/div {:class "app"}
    ($ blog)))

(defn ^:export init []
  (rdom/render ($ app) (js/document.getElementById "app")))
```

The code does compile without any errors. However when open the page in the browser I find a blank page and the following error in the js console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: module$node_modules$react_markdown$index is not a function
    eliashaukssoncom$blog$blog_render blog.cljs:9
    React 15
    eliashaukssoncom$app$init app.cljs:25
    <anonymous> shadow.module.main.append.js:4
    globalEval main.js:472
    evalLoad main.js:1534
    <anonymous> main.js:1848
blog.cljs:9:10
    eliashaukssoncom$blog$blog_render blog.cljs:9
    React 10
    performSyncWorkOnRoot self-hosted:1406
    React 5
    eliashaukssoncom$app$init app.cljs:25
    <anonymous> shadow.module.main.append.js:4
    globalEval main.js:472
    evalLoad main.js:1534
    <anonymous> main.js:1848


The above error occurred in the <eliashaukssoncom.blog/blog> component:

eliashaukssoncom$blog$blog_render@http://localhost:3000/js/cljs-runtime/eliashaukssoncom.blog.js:5:112
RenderedRoute@http://localhost:3000/js/cljs-runtime/module$node_modules$react_router$dist$umd$react_router_development.js:18:17
Routes@http://localhost:3000/js/cljs-runtime/module$node_modules$react_router$dist$umd$react_router_development.js:26:11
Router@http://localhost:3000/js/cljs-runtime/module$node_modules$react_router$dist$umd$react_router_development.js:23:437
shadow$provide.module$node_modules$react_router_dom$dist$umd$react_router_dom_development/</exports.BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/js/cljs-runtime/module$node_modules$react_router_dom$dist$umd$react_router_dom_development.js:37:377
div
eliashaukssoncom$app$app_render@http://localhost:3000/js/cljs-runtime/eliashaukssoncom.app.js:6:112

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

An error occurred when calling (eliashaukssoncom.app/init)

TypeError: module$node_modules$react_markdown$index is not a function
    eliashaukssoncom$blog$blog_render blog.cljs:9
    React 12
    eliashaukssoncom$app$init app.cljs:25
    <anonymous> shadow.module.main.append.js:4
    globalEval main.js:472
    evalLoad main.js:1534
    <anonymous> main.js:1848
main.js:1426:15
    reportError http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1426
    evalLoad http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1536
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:1848
```

If found [this blogpost](https://dev.to/sophiabrandt/how-to-build-a-markdown-preview-app-with-reagent-5d63), which makes use of the `:>` element from [reagent](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent) to achieve the result I need. However I haven't found a way to replicate that with [helix](https://github.com/lilactown/helix).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include a description of the problem that occurs. What happens? Do you get an error? Does it just render nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#api) I'm guessing the correct solution to be

```clj
;; blog.cljs
(ns mypage.blog
  (:require [helix.core :refer [defnc $]]
            [helix.hooks :as hooks]
            [helix.dom :as d]
            ["react-markdown$default" :as ReactMarkdown]))

(defnc blog []
  (d/div {:class "blog-section"}
    ($ ReactMarkdown {:children "# Header\nSome text..."})))
```

This is however just a guess since I don't use any of the libs. Just basing this on translated API examples.

The blog post you referenced is from `Sep 13, 2019` and that is an eternity in the JS world. The `react-markdown` lib likely has gone through a million changes since then and the `:source` prop just no longer exists.